# Prove that every element $S \in SO(n)$ is a product of even numbers of reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Prove that every element $S \in SO(n)$ is a product of even numbers of reflection.
I proved that for SO(2),SO(3) and 2 reflections. How is it with SO(n)?

Comment: Do you know/have you so far been able to show that every element of $SO(n)$ can be written as the product of reflections?

Comment: The even bit comes directly from taking determinants.

Comment: How about showing a rotation can be expressed as a product of two reflections?

Comment: I cann't prove that. 
How from determinants? We know only that they are equal 1.
I think that's remark from that task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Show that there's a reflection $R_n$ that carries $e_n$ to $f_n = S(e_n)$. Note that if $e_n = f_n$, then this "reflection" may have to be the identity map.
2. Now look at the plane of reflection, which contains the vector $ v_n = \frac{e_n + f_n}{2}$. Note that $S(v_n) = v_n$. The hyperplane $H_n$ orthogonal to $v_n$ is mapped to itself under multiplication by $SR_n$ (because multiplication by $S$ preserves inner products, and hence so does $S R_n$).
3. So restrict attention to $H_n$ (which is $n-1$-dimensional); the restriction of $x \mapsto SR_n x$ on this plane is also an orthogonal map, so you can do the same operation: pick a basis $e'_1, e'_2, \ldots, e'_{n-1}$ of $H_n$, find the vector to which $SR_n$ sends $e'_{n-1}$, and build a reflection $R_{n-1}$, construct a hyperplane of dimension $n-2$ called $H_{n-1}$, and repeat.

Eventually, you have

$$
S R_n R_{n-1} \cdots R_1
$$
which is the identity (because it sends $e_n$ to $f_n$ and then back to $e_n$, and sends $e'_{n-1}$ to $f'_{n-1}$ and back again, and so on). Since these vectors that are mapped to themselves form an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb R^n$, the map must be the identity.  So 
$$
S = R_1^{-1} R_2^{-1} \cdots R_n^{-1}.
$$

So this expresses $S$ as a product of "reflections" (one or more of which may be the identity). Eliminating all the identity maps, you get $S$ written as a product of $k$ reflections, each of which has determinant $-1$. Since 
$$
det(S)
$$
is the product of the determinants of the rotations, you have $(-1)^k = 1$, so $k$ must be even.

Comment: How to show $SR_n$ must map $H_n$ to $H_n$ ? I mean how to show $SR_n(H_n)\subset H_n$.

Comment: S is a rotation, so it preserves inner products. $R_n$ is a reflection, so it preserves inner products. Hence $SR_n$ preserves inner products. Suppose $u \in H_n$. Then $u \cdot v_n = 0$, by definition. That means that $(SR_n u) \cdot (S R_n v) = 0$ too. But $R_n v_n = v_n$, because $v_n$ lies in the plane of reflection. And $S(v_n) = v_n$ as well. So $S R_n v_n = v_n$. Hence $(SR_n u \cdot v_n = 0$< so $SR_n u \in H_n$, as required.

Comment: how $S(v_n) = v_n$  ?

Comment: According to your first line ,$R_n(e_n)=f_n=S(e_n)$,  how $S R_n R_{n-1} \cdots R_1$ is identity ?  If so, I have $S(f_n)=e_n$ .