# Some details in proof of SO(n) is product of reflection

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337671/prove-that-every-element-s-in-son-is-a-product-of-even-numbers-of-reflectio) , $S\in SO(n)$ , the main idea is to decompose $S$ to reflection. But I really don't know why $S(v_n)=v_n$ and $SR_n\cdot\cdot\cdot R_1=Id$ ? Who can explain it ? Thanks .

> [image]

Comment: The claim that $S(v_n)=v_n$ is false for general rotations even in the case $n=2$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen  Thanks . In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337671/prove-that-every-element-s-in-son-is-a-product-of-even-numbers-of-reflectio , seemly ,the answer of John Hughes  assume $n>3$ .But I still fail to understand it in the red line  above .

Comment: The same example shows that the claim fails in all dimensions.

Comment: @MoisheCohen  Yes ,your are right .But I feel this way (decompose $S$) is a suitable way to prove it .    If the rotation angle is $\pi$, the proof is ok. But for general situation , it's wrong. How to modify it for general situation ?

Comment: I do not care for the proof that is written. Do you need a hint for a correct proof?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I really need it . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Step 1. Prove the claim in the case of orthogonal transformations in the plane. Step 2: Use the normal form for orthogonal transformations in the general dimension (existence of invariant  decomposition of the space as the direct sum of pairwise orthogonal subspaces of dimension at most 2).